# Function won't return any value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function

I have a problem that I think might be really easy to solve but since I'm a C# noob I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have two functions: `addValues()` and `showMessage()`. My problem is in `addValues()`. I have two `MessageBox` that show exactly what they're supposed to show, but in the `showMessage()` function the values are not being received, it always tells me that the day and `dias.Count` are 0. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

On Form1:

```
  public List<Despesas> dias = new List<Despesas>();
    public struct Despesas
    {
        public double transportes;
        public double alimentacao;
        public double vestuario;
        public double agua;
        public double luz;
        public double educacao;
    }
```

On Class Management:

```
class management : Form1
{
    int day=0;

public double addValues(double transportes, double alimentacao)
{
    Despesas dia = new Despesas();
    try
    {
        dia.transportes = transportes;
        dia.agua = agua;
        dias.Add(dia);
     }
     catch
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Count " + dias.Count);
     day++;
     MessageBox.Show("" + day);
     return day;
}

 public void showMessage()
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Day " + day);
     MessageBox.Show("Count: " " + dias.Count);
     for (int i = 0; i < day; i++)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Agua: " + dias[i].agua + "\nTransportes: " + dias[i].transportes);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure `addValues` is being called? The bug does not appear to be in the provided code

Comment: Yes, I'm sure since the MessageBox is showed when it's called.

Comment: Are you sure addValues is called?

I don't see the definition of agua

Comment: Showing a message box is different than `addValues` being called. If you set a breakpoint in that function, do you hit it?

Comment: so it seems these are global `agua` and `dias`

Comment: Show us where you set `dias` array and where you set `day` and how you mutate them. This is not provided in your code here. No one can help you this way we can only guess. I am guessing you are not mutating `dias` and so showMessage is acting on a new array with no elements and you get 0.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It is being called because the day and dias.Count values are being incremented. But only on that function.

Comment: @MiguelPT Clearly `day` and `dias` are not local variables (unless you aren't showing us something), so changes to them would propagate to the other functions. There is *something* you aren't showing us.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I added the rest of the Code.

Comment: Do you have two different instances of `management`? As an aside, I'm not sure inheritance is the right answer here...

Comment: But you are not calling addValues before showMessage are you?

Comment: Why does `management` inherit from Form1?  That seems odd to me for a new programmer.  Do you have a good grasp of inheritance?

Comment: Where is `addValues` being called?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes I have another instance of management because I don't know another way to call a function inside another class without it being static or creating a new instance of that class.

Comment: @Saher Yes, I'm calling addValues before showMessage, shouldn't I ?

Comment: @LarsTech Management inherits from Form1 because the struct used in management is declared in Form1

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, you mention that you actually have *two* instances of the `management` class.

Changes to one instance of an object do not propagate to other instances of that object (unless it was modified on a `static` member, but thats a bit different).

This holds true even if you modify a base class member, as your code does. This is because instantiation of a derived class *also* instantiates a new base class object.

The solution is to just use one `management` object instance, and pass it around as needed. You do this just like any other type:

```
public void Foo(management myClass)
{
   ...
}
```

A few other notes:

- `management` is not a very good name for a class, as its not very descriptive. Also, class names in C# should be PascalCase, so it should be `Management`
- Inheritance is probably not the right relationship between `management` and `Form1`. Is `management` really a "type of" or "is a" `Form1`?

Comment: But how do I do that? Can you please explain?

Comment: I think I did. Can you clarify what piece is confusing you?

Comment: I don't understand what public void Foo(management myClass) does...

Comment: @MiguelPT Its just a sample function that accepts a parameter of your object type. Perhaps there is a piece of how methods/paramters work I could explain?